# How can I export each NLA animation as a separate FBX file?

Tags: animation, rigging, export

In the *FBX Export Settings > Bake Animation* I tried activating *NLA Strips* and *All Actions* but only the skeletal mesh gets exported.

It's for Blender to UE5 workflow.

I was using Send2UE but the addon is dead so I'm searching for a reliable alternative.

Comment: Why you need separate file? You can just import file to UE 5 and you should have separate actions there.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrug I have +40 animations in one .blend file each with its own NLA strip, I'd prefer to just reimport the ones that I'm working on instead of all of them all the time.

Comment: thats actually good reason I would also just reimport single animation, but don't know how to do that yet :P